# CPU running to slow

Tags: cpu-speed, throttling

My laptop's (a Dell Studio XPS) CPU appears to be being throttled. It's an Intel Core Duo P8600 2.4hGhz running windows 10.

Perf mon is reporting its speed as 1.58Ghz rather than 2.4Ghz

The temp is 58 degrees per core (its rated to 105).
The power plan is high  performance (100% CPU).
Ive tried disabling Speed Step in the bios - no change.

In the event Log Ive found "information":

Processor 1 in group 0 exposes the following power management capabilities:

Idle state type: ACPI Idle (C) States (3 state(s))

Performance state type: ACPI Performance (P) / Throttle (T) States
Nominal Frequency (MHz): 2394
Maximum performance percentage: 100
Minimum performance percentage: 100
Minimum throttle percentage: 13

This started happening about a week ago.

Sometimes a hard reboot resets the performance to 2.4 but within half an hour its back at 1.5 or sometimes 0.79!

All this is happening when the machine is plugged into the mains.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's an old machine, have you opened it up to clear dust out out of the fans and heatsinks? You might also need to look at replacing thermal pads or materials.

Comment: I've cleaned out the fan, which is as a result on a lot less, but the temps were always around 50 degrees anyway.